# Am I handling the 'public' directory the right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, email, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1.1 and I want to add a linked image - my app's logo - in email messages but I had a doubt since my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571213/some-issues-acessing-asset-files-in-production-mode).

By using files located in the `public` directory it seems that *to link to an image in your Asset Pipeline* you can use

```
link_to(LINK_TEXT_OR_IMAGE_TAG_HELPER, image_path(IMAGE_NAME))
```

*but* for those located in the `app/assets` it seems *do not work the same*, at least in rendered email messages in production mode. *All assets that are compiled in Production have a fingerprint ID*... is the fingerprint causing the load of static assets to do not render images in email messages?

I doubt since I would like to access images from both browser and email. I tried to solve the issue by moving the image from `app/assets/images/logo.png` to `public/images/logo.png` and by changing statements in my `application.css.scss` file from `image-url("logo.png")` to `url("/images/logos.png")`. However I do not know if I am following "the Rails way" or a "best practice". Do I? Should I add to the `public` directory all assets that I plan to use outside my application and in the `app/assets` directory all assets that I plan to use internally to my application?

Comment: Fingerprint is based on asset's content. If you don't change the logo, it should stay the same across deploys (that is, safe to reference from email)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - I tried to reference from email the logo image located in the `app/assets` directory and it is not accessible. If I put the image in the `public` directory (making the proper code changes as in the question) then the image is accessible.

Comment: Did you do `rake assets:precompile` ? Are you running in production or development mode? How does the generated link look?

Comment: @nathanvda - 1) I did try... 2) I am speaking of both modes since they doesn't work the same way in cases when a) using the RoR 4 feature "Previewing mailers" in development and when b) rendering HTML email messages in production mode. 3) Running in development the generated link looks like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/logo.png` and in production it looks like `https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LYF...t#http://www.my_app_name.org/assets/logo.png` - from GMail source code.

Comment: In the first case it does work. In the second it doesn't since the link image is broken - by logging the production server I get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/logo.png")`.

Comment: I solved this issue in two different ways  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572521/how-can-i-use-assets-within-mailer or in config/enviornments/production.rb ensure that  config.serve_static_assets = true

Answer (score 0):

For emails, it almostisn't any different compared to standard Rails views.

You can link to an image in your mailer using the `image_tag` helper you'd normally use in regular views as well:

```
<%= image_tag('some_image.jpg') %>
```

You also need to tell Action Mailer where it can find the assets, because it will use absolute URLs to refer to your images:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://www.example.com/'
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. It works if I put images in the `public` directory and making the code changes as in the question.

Comment: can you paste image path you are getting in the email when image is not in public directory and you are using image_path?

Comment: @Shweta - See my last comments to the question.